# (QGIS) Import photos - direction is null

Tags: qgis, direction

I have some pictures taken with my mini 3 pro. I'm trying to use the wedge feature to show image direction but am not having any success.

After reviewing the attribute table it is showing the direction as null. Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, it looks like you are using the Import Geotagged Photos tool under the Processing Toolbox - Vector Creation.

Your findings are correct.  This looks like a shortfall of the Import Geotagged Photos Tool.

Using [gdalinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html) to read the DJI Mini 3 Pro EXIF data we see that there is no azimuth data returned by gdalinfo. Here is a screen shot of the GPS specific EXIF tags returned by gdalinfo for a Mini 3 Pro:
[image]

Using an application like [EXIFtool](https://exiftool.org/) you can see that there are, in fact, azimuth values stored in the image metadata.  Here is a screen shot of the EXIFtool return:
[image]

There are azimuth values as gimble yaw values. These gimble tags are actually stored a XMP tags as determined by DJI, and I guess, not exploited by the Import Geotagged Photos tool.  To be fair to  Import Geotagged Photos tool these values and tags are not standardized and vary between GNSS enabled camera manufactures. The coders would be faced with a lot of different tags and units of measure to account for.

I am unsure of your options.  I have developed Python code to return a KML with camera angle displayed as an arrow but found that my DJI Mini Pro 3 returned an azimuth that was not correct.  [See here](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/dji-mini-3-pro-exif-azimuth-is-11-degrees-west-of-true-north) for more information on this subject. I would be interested to know if your camera has the same error angles.

My azimuth/KML Python code works for Debian Linux and is untested on Windows.  Comment back on whether you are interested in this code, if so, I will get that tool uploaded to github later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a Linux system so I won't be able to use your script. Very informative feedback though. Maybe my only option unfortunately would be paid drone processing software?

Comment: Ah, I see that some of my Python libraries are specific to Linux and not easily available on Windows.  There is the Windows Subsystem for Linux not available on Windows.  I don't know of any drone processing software to give you points with image direction.  Have you tried the Vertical Photo Placer plugin for QGIS?  If you can accept my answer I would appreciate it.

Comment: Done! Thank you for saving me from going down rabit holes to try and figure this out! Now get cracking with your coding skills and fix up the import photo plug in to work with DJI drones haha!

Comment: Regarding your question for the 11 degrees error: Have you ever tried to make an orthomosaic and see if it the image lines up with imagery? Maybe that would eliminate your questions as to if your drone is a lemon?

Comment: No issues with orthos from the MM3P due to the azimuth errors in the XMP data.  I do have scripts that will leverage those data and auto-georference images based on those values and those outputs are skewed.